# Entropy rate for continuous variables?

Tags: references, entropy, information-theory

**Question:** Is the concept of entropy rate defined for real-valued random processes? If so, does it have the same interpretation as in the discrete case; and how can it be estimated?

**Background:** As far as I know, the entropy rate of a random process is defined as:

$$ h = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}H(X_1, ..., H_n) \,.$$

In conventional, finite-alphabet information theory the entropy rate of a process quantifies how many bits this process generates per realization. That is different from the entropy of the realizations themselves $H(X_i)$.

However, if the $X_i$ are continuous variables the notion of entropy $H(X_i)$ doesn't have the same interpretation as in the discrete case, since it isn't non-negative and is not invariant under change of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the *differential entropy rate* of a continuous process, but like [differential entropy lacks the interpretability of entropy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256203/how-to-interpret-differential-entropy/), it will not be as meaningful as entropy rate.

To estimate the (differential) entropy rate, you can you exploit the fact that for a *stationary* process

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} H[X_1, ..., X_n] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} H[X_n \mid X_{n - 1}..., X_1].$$

This allows you to estimate the entropy rate by estimating the entropy of a conditional distribution. In practice, you will likely also make a Markov assumption and only take into account the last $m$ steps. Using an estimate of the conditional probability, $\hat P(x_{n} \mid x_{n - 1}, ..., x_{n - m})$, approximate the conditional entropy with the [cross-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy)
$$E_P[-\log \hat P(X_{n} \mid X_{n - 1}, ..., X_{n - m})].$$
This approximation is guaranteed to be an upper bound on the true entropy rate.