# Why is Shannon entropy score lower for distributions with higher variance?

Tags: r, entropy

Hi I'm perplexed because I assume that a distribution with higher variance should have higher entropy scores, however this does not appear to be the case?
Here is an example.

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(0)

# High Variance Probe: Uniform distribution
high_variance_probe <- runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1)

# Low Variance Probe: Normal distribution, but tightly clustered
mean <- 0.5
std_dev <- 0.1
low_variance_probe <- rnorm(1000, mean = mean, sd = std_dev)
low_variance_probe <- pmin(pmax(low_variance_probe, 0), 1) # Clipping values to [0, 1]

entropy::entropy (high_variance_probe)
entropy::entropy (low_variance_probe)
```

high variance is: 6.717094
low variable_probe is: 6.886953

why is this the case?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see at least two explanations:

1. Shannon entropy is defined for *discrete* random variables. The extension to the continuous case is called differential entropy, though its interpretation is less straightforward and arguably less meaningful or useful, see for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256203/how-to-interpret-differential-entropy/256238#256238) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Entropy_for_continuous_random_variables).
2. The `entropy::entropy` function only calculates Shannon entropy (discrete case) and is coded to accept *counts* *per* *bin*, that is, you have to pre-summarize your data. Consider the following code example:

```
set.seed(1)
## Low variance discrete variable
low <- sample(1:5, size=1E5, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1,1,10,1,1))
## High variance discrete variable
high <- sample(1:5, size=1E5, replace=TRUE)

## Incorrect usage
entropy::entropy(low)
> 11.47
entropy::entropy(high)
> 11.39

## Correct usage
entropy::entropy(table(low))
> 0.9953
entropy::entropy(table(high))
> 1.6094
```

Comment: I see now, thank you.